# Insert an int value into a foreign key in ASP.NET MVC & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can't insert the `idmodello` value in `FkModelloAutomobile`, intellisense requests a `ModelloAutomobile` type, not an `int` type:

```
ModelloAutomobile modello = new ModelloAutomobile();
int idmodello = Convert.ToInt32(form["ModelloId"].ToString());
modello = await service.GetProductByIdAsync(idmodello);
Mappatura.FkModelloAutomobile = idmodello;
```

`Mappatura` model class:

```
public class Mappatura
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Applicazioni { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Settaggi { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Ecu { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Dettagli { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Costo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DirectoryMappatura { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ModelloAutomobile FkModelloAutomobile { get; set; }
}
```

`ModelloAutomobile` model class:

```
public class ModelloAutomobile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NomeModello { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TipoMotore { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Alimentazione { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Potenza { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Anno { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual MarcaAutomobile FkMarcaAutomobile { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a property in the Mappatura class like this:

```
public int ModelloAutomobileId { get; set; }
```

That property maps to the Id property of the ModelloAutomobile class.

Comment: `code public int FkModelloAutomobileId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey( "FkModelloAutomobileId" )]
        public virtual ModelloAutomobile FkModelloAutomobile { get; set; }`

Comment: thanks you! i just added `[ForeignKey( "FkModelloAutomobileId" )] `